# Dataweave update a JSON field based on another JSON field

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft

I want to update the payload.title value with the comparing the second JSON. In below payload.title value `'Mr.'` should be updated with secondJson `xrefValue` value of `'Mister'`. The comparing condition is payload.value should equal to `secondJson.masterObjectValues[0].code`, then the payload.title value should update with xrefValue value where `systemCode` = `SYS2`.

Could you please help me to sort this using data weave language?

payload =

```
{
"patient": {
"patientNumber": "123",
"secondaryAltPatientIdentifier": "2222222",
"title": "Mr.",
"preferredName": "test"
}
}
```

secondJson=

```
{
  "objectCode": "Title",
  "masterObjectValues": [
    {
      "systemCode": "MASTER",
      "systemObjectValues": [
        {
          "codeId": "a5G9p0000001HwTEAU",
          "code": "Dr.",
          "crossRef": [
            {
              "systemCode": "BBS",
              "xrefValue": "DR"
            },
            {
              "systemCode": "NAVSYD",
              "xrefValue": "DR"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "codeId": "a5G9p0000001HurEAE",
          "code": "Mr.",
          "crossRef": [
            {
              "systemCode": "BBS",
              "xrefValue": "MR"
            },
            {
              "systemCode": "SYS2",
              "xrefValue": "Mister"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm expecting the output as,

payload =

```
{
"patient": {
"patientNumber": "123",
"secondaryAltPatientIdentifier": "2222222",
"title": "Mister",
"preferredName": "test"
}
}
```

Comment: secondJson is invalid. Please fix it in the question.

Comment: The input and expected payloads are invalid too. They miss the end curly brace.

Comment: Hi @aled the JSON has been updated. Can you please help me now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `update` operator to change the value of a field. Then use `filter()` to find the elements in the arrays that match a condition. I'm assuming that there is always a valid match in my solution. I filter first by the `title` and the `systemCode`.

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var secondJson={
    "objectCode": "Title",
    "masterObjectValues": [
        {
            "systemCode": "MASTER",
            "systemObjectValues": [
                {
                    "codeId": "112",
                    "code": "Dr.",
                    "crossRef": [
                        {
                            "systemCode": "UAT",
                            "xrefValue": "DR"
                        },
                        {
                            "systemCode": "SYS2",
                            "xrefValue": "DR"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "codeId": "113",
                    "code": "Mr.",
                    "crossRef": [
                        {
                            "systemCode": "UAT",
                            "xrefValue": "MR"
                        },
                        {
                            "systemCode": "SYS2",
                            "xrefValue": "Mister"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
---
payload update {
    case patient at .patient -> patient update {
        case title at .title -> ((secondJson.masterObjectValues[0].systemObjectValues filter ($.code == title)) [0].crossRef filter ($.systemCode=="SYS2"))[0].xrefValue 
    }
}
```

Output:

```json
{
  "patient": {
    "patientNumber": "111",
    "secondaryAltPatientIdentifier": "2222222",
    "title": "Mister",
    "preferredName": "abc"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi aled, this is what i needed. Thank you very much for your response. :)

Answer (score 0):

Another way of transforming this

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var secondJson={
  "objectCode": "Title",
  "masterObjectValues": [
    {
      "systemCode": "MASTER",
      "systemObjectValues": [
        {
          "codeId": "a5G9p0000001HwTEAU",
          "code": "Dr.",
          "crossRef": [
            {
              "systemCode": "BBS",
              "xrefValue": "DR"
            },
            {
              "systemCode": "NAVSYD",
              "xrefValue": "DR"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "codeId": "a5G9p0000001HurEAE",
          "code": "Mr.",
          "crossRef": [
            {
              "systemCode": "BBS",
              "xrefValue": "MR"
            },
            {
              "systemCode": "SYS2",
              "xrefValue": "Mister"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
var y = secondJson.masterObjectValues.systemObjectValues[0] groupBy $.code mapObject ((value, key, index) -> 
    (key) : {(value.crossRef[0] map (
        {
            ($.systemCode) : $.xrefValue
        }
     ) )}
)
 
---
payload  update {
    case .patient.title -> y[$].SYS2
}
```